# How can I make flatDir work with multiple JARs of same name but different versions

Tags: java, gradle

I've encountered a situation where Gradle does not seem to handle a flatDir containing multiple JARs of the same name.

I'm trying to create a configuration that includes both ANTLR 3.1.3 and ANTLR 2.7.7, as oddly 3.1.3 happens to depend on 2.7.7.

`build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java'

configurations {
   antlr3
}

dependencies {
    antlr3 "org.antlr:antlr:3.1.3"
    antlr3 "org.antlr:antlr:2.7.7"
    antlr3 "org.antlr:antlr-runtime:3.1.3"
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
         dir projectDir
    }
}

task horse {
    doLast {
        configurations.antlr3.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.file.each {
             println it
         }
    }
}
```

On disk:

```
./antlr-2.7.7.jar
./antlr-3.1.3.jar
./antlr-runtime-3.1.3.jar
./build.gradle
```

What happens is only the first dependency is setup, so `gradle horse`

```
:horse
/home/socky-wocky-do-dah/project-3/antlr-3.1.3.jar
/home/socky-wocky-do-dah/project-3/antlr-runtime-3.1.3.jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

If you swap the order of the dependencies the 2.7.7 JAR is resolved.

How can I get Gradle to bring in both the 3.1.3 and 2.7.7 JARs when using `flatDir`?

Comment: Just curious, where did you see the dependency of `3.1.3` on `2.7.7`? I could not find it in MavenCentral.

Comment: The dependency goes from antlr -> antlr-master -> antlr:2.7.7. You can see it in https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/antlr/antlr-master/3.1.3/antlr-master-3.1.3.pom. This isn't an error.... it appears that 3.1.3 JAR still contains references to the old package structure from 2.x... namely references to antlr.ANTLRException.